# Story/article about the 1969 moon landing's meaning to a black man

Tags: identification-request, short-stories

Can you help me identify the short story or article?

- It was set in Florida in the summer of 1969
- The writer asks a black man, working at his hotel, what he thinks of the excitement over the moon landing
- The black man answers along the lines of "Do you see any black man on the moon or on TV? Until then it means nothing."

Comment: related: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=goh2x_G0ct4&ab_channel=AceRecordsLtd - Gil Scott-Heron's spoken-word piece "Whitey on the Moon"

Comment: See also the Guardian article ['Whitey's on the moon': why Apollo 11 looked so different to black America](https://www.theguardian.com/science/2019/jul/14/apollo-11-civil-rights-black-america-moon).